# Rellenar una matriz de forma aleatoria pero con restricciones

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Supongamos que tenemos esta matriz donde se deben de cumplir las siguientes reglas:
Filas 1,2 y 3 tienen que sumar 4, la cuarta fila sumará 5 y la última solo 3. La suma de cada columna por separado a,b,c,d siempre sumarán 5.

```
 a   b    c   d  | total 
--- ---  --- --- |-------
 a1  b1   c1   d1 |  4  
 a2  b2   c2   d2 |  4  
 a3  b3   c3   d3 |  4  
 a4  b4   c4   d4 |  5  
 a5  b5   c5   d5 |  3  
--- ---  ---  ---|------
5    5    5    5 | 20
```

Rellenarla de forma manual no es muy complicado recordandome en cierto modo al sudoku o incluso al problema de las 8 reinas.

Una posible solución.

```
 a   b   c   d  | total 
--- --- --- --- |-------
 3   1   0   0  |  4  
 0   2   0   2  |  4  
 2   0   0   2  |  4  
 0   1   3   1  |  5  
 0   1   2   0  |  3  
--- --- --- --- |------
 5   5   5   5  |  20
```

Mi algoritmo consiste en ir rellenando fila por fila aleatoriamente cumpliendo las condiciones tanto de la fila como de la columna.

El problema viene cuando llego al final que no tiene porque coincidir con una solución (se muestran X en el ejemplo que he puesto).

¿Qué solución puede tener esto? A ser posible sin utilizar recursividad.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", ejecutar);

function ejecutar() {
    m = {
        f1: { a:0, b:0, c:0, d:0 },
        f2: { a:0, b:0, c:0, d:0 },
        f3: { a:0, b:0, c:0, d:0 },
        f4: { a:0, b:0, c:0, d:0 },
        f5: { a:0, b:0, c:0, d:0 },
    }
    // maximos de cada fila y columna
    max = { a:5, b:5, c:5, d:5 , f1:4, f2:4, f3:4, f4:5, f5:3 };

    m.f1.a = random("f1","a");
    m.f1.b = random("f1","b");
    m.f1.c = random("f1","c");
    m.f1.d = random("f1","d");
    m.f2.a = random("f2","a");
    m.f2.b = random("f2","b");
    m.f2.c = random("f2","c");
    m.f2.d = random("f2","d");
    m.f3.a = random("f3","a");
    m.f3.b = random("f3","b");
    m.f3.c = random("f3","c");
    m.f3.d = random("f3","d");
    m.f4.a = random("f4","a");
    m.f4.b = random("f4","b");
    m.f4.c = random("f4","c");
    m.f4.d = random("f4","d");
    m.f5.a = random("f5","a");
    m.f5.b = random("f5","b");
    m.f5.c = random("f5","c");
    m.f5.d = random("f5","d");

    var html = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        var f = m["f"+i];
        var ok = (max["f"+i]!=0) ? "<b>X</b>" : "";
        html += '<tr><td><b>f'+i+'</b></td><td>'+f.a+'</td><td>'+f.b+'</td><td>'+f.c+'</td><td>'+f.d+'</td> <td>'+ok+'</td></tr>';
    }
    var a = (max.a!=0) ? "<b>X</b>" : "";
    var b = (max.b!=0) ? "<b>X</b>" : "";
    var c = (max.c!=0) ? "<b>X</b>" : "";
    var d = (max.d!=0) ? "<b>X</b>" : "";
    html += '<tr><td></td><td>'+a+'</td><td>'+b+'</td><td>'+c+'</td><td>'+d+'</td></tr>';
    var matrix = document.getElementById('matrix').innerHTML = html;
}

function random(fila,col) { 
    maximo = (max[fila] > max[col]) ? max[col] : max[fila];
    // console.log("max = "+ maximo);
    if (col == "d") {
        var  dato = maximo;
    } else {
        var dato = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximo + 1));
    }
    max[fila] = max[fila] - dato;
    max[col] = max[col] - dato;

    return dato;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">ejecutar</button>
<table id="matris" class="blueTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="matrix">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Si hace eso, las tres primeras filas y columnas pueden ser aleatorias.. pero la última fila y la última columna están determinadas por el resto y el resultado.

Comment: @Takyo Igual no queda claro cuales son las restricciones.. y si, si se puede resolver recursivamente, se puede resolver iterativamente (aunque parezca mas complicado el codigo)

Comment: Sigo sin saber cuales son las reglas para llenar esa matriz...

Comment: @gbianch editado con una mejor explicación

Comment: Y donde estaria lo aleatorio? porque una vez que definiste a1, casi que definiste el resto de la fila...

Comment: a1 es aleatorio, las letras no vienen predefinidas nunca. Digamos que a1+b1+c1+d1 = 4  y la suma de todas las a es 5. busco una manera de generar soluciones al problema que hay muchas

Comment: Creo que me has entendido, lo que salga en a1 condicionará el resto de letras, tanto en la fila como en la columna.Te animo a que me edites para que se entienda mejor lo que busco. un saludo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88750/discussion-between-takyo-and-gbianchi).